# Atualizar o estado ao clicar no textFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou recebendo dados de uma API e utilizando o `ConnectionState` para saber o estado da conexão e exibir um `CircularProgressIndicator` ao usuário enquanto a conexão for `waiting` ou `none` e exibir o conteúdo quando estiver em `done` porém sempre que clico em um `TextFormField` ele reseta a API e recarrega assim fechando o teclado e repetindo o processo já tentei com `if` `else`, `switch` `case`, `while` e sempre da na mesma

```
body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        dolar = snapshot.data!["results"]["currencies"]["USD"]["buy"];
        euro = snapshot.data!["results"]["currencies"]["EUR"]["buy"];
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: StackBody(
              windowHeigth: windowHeigth,
              windowWidth: windowWidth,
              controllerDolar: controllerDolar,
              controllerEuro: controllerEuro),
        );
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) da classe `FutureBuilder`:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, [...].
> It must not be created during the State.build [...]. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Traduzindo livremente, isso significa que você não deve *criar* a conexão dentro do `FutureBuilder`. Você fez isso na linha `future: getData(),`. Quando você faz isso, sempre que essa parte da tela for re-desenhada, a função irá ser chamada de novo e a conexão será resetada.

Existem muitos jeitos de resolver esse problema, mas o mais simples é:

1. Iniciar essa conexão no `initState`.
2. Armazenar seu resultado em uma variável da classe de estado.
3. No `futureBuilder`, use a variável que você armazenou.

No seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    conexao = getData(); // Passo 1: Chame a função dentro do initState e armazene em uma variável.
  }

late Future<Map> conexao; // Passo 2: A variável criada.

[...]

body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
    future: conexao, // Passo 3: Usar no FutureBuilder o future armazenado.
```